# Double sorting an array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I need to sort an array in  PHP and then sort by its second index if the first index is the same. Let me explain :

The elements would be randomly arranged :

```
(2,1),(4,4),(2,9),(4,8),(2,35),(2,1),(2,35),(4,4),(4,25),(4,4)
```

I would need to sort them by the first number first. so the result would be :

```
(2,1),(2,9),(2,1),(2,35),(4,4),(4,8),(4,4),(4,25),(4,4)
```

Now you can see all the elements are grouped by the first index together. Now i need to group by the second index "WITHIN" the current grouping. Thus make it look like :

```
(2,1),(2,1),(2,9),(2,35),(4,4),(4,4),(4,4),(4,8),(4,25)
```

This was just a simple representation of the array. The actual array is below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 119
            [practice_location_id] => 173
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 2
            [practice_location_id] => 75
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 18
            [practice_location_id] => 28
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 119
            [practice_location_id] => 174
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 119
            [practice_location_id] => 173
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 2
            [practice_location_id] => 75
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 119
            [practice_location_id] => 174
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 18
            [practice_location_id] => 28
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [practice_id] => 18
            [practice_location_id] => 27
        )
)
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you sure you need to sort this in PHP? If you're getting the data from some kind of database, it would be much simpler to make the sort there.

Comment: no, it has to be done in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This callback uses what I just learned from @casablanca's answer, and puts it in a loop.  This way, it won't just compare two, but as many keys there are to compare.

```
function sort_callback($x, $y)
    foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
        if ($x[$key] != $y[$key])
            return $x[$key] - $y[$key];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As already stated, give this function as a callback to usort().

http://php.net/usort

Answer (score 6):

Use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom comparison function, which sorts by the first field, but if they are equal, sorts by the second field:

```
function my_compare($a, $b) {
  if ($a['practice_id'] == $b['practice_id'])
    return $a['practice_location_id'] - $b['practice_location_id'];
  else
    return $a['practice_id'] - $b['practice_id'];
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that you could return _any_ negative/positive number, not just -1 or 1.  Good to know.

Comment: @Jonah Bron: That's how `strcmp` in C works, and it has carried on to many other languages.

Comment: Er, you mean `strcmp` only allows -1, 0, or +1?  Or the other way around?

Comment: @Jonah Bron: No, I meant `strcmp` returns *any* negative, zero or positive value as per the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
function compare_callback($x, $y) {
    if ($x['practice_id'] < $y['practice_id'])
        return 1;
    if ($x['practice_id'] > $y['practice_id'])
        return -1;
    if ($x['practice_id'] == $y['practice_id']) {
        if ($x['practice_location_id'] < $y['practice_location_id'])
            return 1;
        if ($x['practice_location_id'] > $y['practice_location_id'])
            return -1;
        if ($x['practice_location_id'] == $y['practice_location_id'])
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Use this method with usort()

http://php.net/usort

Comment: Seeing it this way helped a whole lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`usort()`-function](http://php.net/usort):

```
function someCompareFunction($a, $b) {
    $order = array('practice_id', 'practice_location_id');

    foreach ($order as $key) {
        if (isset($a[$key]) && isset($b[$key]) && $a[$key] != $b[$key]) {
            return $a[$key] - $b[$key];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

usort($yourArray, 'someCompareFunction');
```

The following is possible as of PHP 5.3:

```
usort($yourArray, function($a, $b) {
    // comparison code
});
```

You can make your compare-function as complex as you need it.

Comment: Good, but it doesn't answer how to compare a secondary level.

Comment: @Jonah Bron: I added that now ;)